# ColdFusion Tag is not supported

Tags: coldfusion, tags, railo, cfgrid, cfwebsocket

I am new to `ColdFusion` and downloaded the [latest version of Railo](http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/download/) which is [compatible with ColdFusion 10](http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/documentation/compatibility/cfml-compatibility/).

I want to use the `CFGrid` and `CFWebsocket` tags which are included in Adobe's ColdFusion 10`, as you can see in the documentation.

But when I start my application, an error says that these tags are not supported.

Comment: Paste your code dave... it's a good bet there's something else. Both cfgrid and cfwebsocket are supported as of v10 - though I wonder if cfwebsocket was an enterprise only tag?

Comment: Railo 4.2 is roughly compatible with CF10, but there are some things it doesn't support, among them `cfgrid` and `cfwebsocket`.

Comment: @CfSimplicity, you should post that as an answer.  It's also worth noting that you can write extensions to Railo to implement tags too.  The CFSpreadsheet tag is an example of a community-supported Railo tag that is not part of the core.

Comment: Since the OP is new to CFML, it's worth mentioning that tags like cfgrid and cfwebsocket don't get much love from either the Coldfusion community or the Railo/Lucee community.  As general advice, write CFML code that outputs clean HTML and use Javascript libraries like jQuery to provide client-side functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Railo 4.2 is roughly compatible with CF10, but there are some things it doesn't support, among them `cfgrid` and `cfwebsocket`.